# Считывание введённой математической функции c++\c#

Tags: c#, c++, математика

Возникла идея для курсовой просчёт интеграла методом Симпсона,но возникла проблема при считывании математической функции программой. Насколько реально написать код,который будет любое введённое уравнение преобразовывать в функцию,к открой можно будет легко обратиться ? Язык в предпочтении c#

Comment: ответ: полностью реально. Я рад что смог тебе помочь.

Comment: "любое введённое уравнение" - полностью нереально

Comment: @Igor мне вот интересно, если "полностью нереально", то как работают MathCad и, скажем, ввод формул текстом(а не через редактор формул) в ворде? :)

Comment: Если вводить текст функции прямо на языке программирования, то его можно скомпилировать, положить в shared library и потом вызывать динамически.

Comment: @Andrew MathCad может интерпретировать далеко не "любое введённое уравнение". Запишите в нём, например, функцию Дирихле? Ну а ввод формул в текстовый редактор вообще никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет.

Comment: @Yaant `Ну а ввод формул в текстовый редактор вообще никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет` есть часть вопроса касающийся ввода, есть часть касающийся инерпритации введенной формулы. Это разные задачи, и, внезапно, они решаются абсолютно по-разному. Пример с вордом касается именно ввода формулы, но никак не ее интерпритации и расчета по ней. И это хорошая практика заимствовать чужой опыт. В даном случае - опыт записи формул на основе синтаксиса используемого в ворде, а он, в достаточной мере интуитивный.

Comment: @Yaant `Запишите в нём, например, функцию Дирихле?` гугл мне выдал вот это: http://matlab.exponenta.ru/signalprocess/book1/18/diric.php :) Так что, судя по всему, это возможно в MATLAB.

Comment: @Andrew Это не та функция Дирихле. :) Я имел в виду [вот эту](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5) :)

Answer (score 0):

Относительно простой вариант:

- Читаете про [обратную польскую нотацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) и разбираетесь, как вычислять записанные таким способом выражения. Это довольно просто.
- Реализуете [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), который переводит выражения из обычной (инфиксной) нотации в обратную польскую.

---

Альтернатива - найти готовую библиотеку. Гугл подсказывает [вот что](http://mathparser.org/).